# Remote Backup MySQL database with routines unsuccess

Tags: mysql

```
mysqldump -u root --password=123456 -h 110.4.43.111 --databases db_shuttlebus --routines --lock-tables=true --result-file=D:\Server-Backup.sql
```

everything has backuped, but the Routines are not backuped, why? what wrong with my command?

in Routines i have a function, but can't backuped.

[image]

### UPDATE

```
DELIMITER ;;
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50020 DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`*/ /*!50003 PROCEDURE `GenerateRouteFare`(
pRoute_ID int
)
BEGIN
-- SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0; 
-- DELETE FROM tbl_rate WHERE Route_ID = pRoute_ID;

INSERT INTO tbl_rate (Route_ID,From_LocationID,To_LocationID,Normal_Rate,Discounted_Rate)
select 
   a.Route_ID,  
   a.Route_LocationID from_loc_id, 
   b.Route_LocationID to_loc_id, 
   0,0

from tbl_route a 
inner join tbl_route b on a.Route_ID = b.Route_ID and a.Route_Seq < b.Route_Seq and a.Route_ID = pRoute_ID
inner join tbl_location la on la.Location_ID = a.Route_LocationID
inner join tbl_location lb on lb.Location_ID = b.Route_LocationID
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT Rate_ID
                    FROM tbl_rate
                   WHERE tbl_rate.From_LocationID = a.Route_LocationID AND tbl_rate.To_LocationID = b.Route_LocationID AND Route_ID = pRoute_ID)
order by a.Route_Seq, b.Route_Seq;

-- DELETE 
DELETE 
  FROM tbl_rate 
 WHERE Rate_ID IN
(
  SELECT Rate_ID
    FROM
  (

select * from tbl_rate  WHERE Route_ID= pRoute_ID AND CONCAT(From_LocationID, ',', To_LocationID) 
NOT IN 
(select CONCAT(a.Route_LocationID,',', b.Route_LocationID) as Locname from tbl_route a 
inner join tbl_route b on a.Route_ID = b.Route_ID and a.Route_Seq < b.Route_Seq and a.Route_ID = pRoute_ID) 

  ) q
);
END */;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Did you actually open `Server-Backup.sql` and see if there are routines inside? Search for `CREATE FUNCTION` or `CREATE PROCEDURE` in your sql file to see if routines are exported.

Comment: @D.Kasipovic i have found that routines are inside `Server-Backup.sql`,but why when execute the `Server-Backup.sql` routines are not restore in Database?

Comment: Maybe the user which you are using for import does not have privilege to create procedures? You should run your sql file manually and see what error does it give you. Do you get any errors while importing? This is know to happen if procedures/functions have been created as `user1@host` on server from which you are exporting, but the same user does not exist in server you are importing to. Do your functions/procedures have `DEFINER` attribute and does user specified in `DEFINER` actually exists on your server to which you are importing?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic Yes, with DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` but both database also same name root. should be no problem

Comment: Have you tried copy and paste of your CREATE FUNCTION statement in your sql management software, and see if there are errors?

Comment: @D.Kasipovic if i execute those command i have update in my question, nothing happen, dont have any success or error, and then i have deleted all the `/*!50003` similiar words, and it is success created function. why?

Comment: if you wants to backup db..

Comment: What versions are your source and target database?